# Add a comma after two digits in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to add a comma between numbers in all the column.

My data is a percentage, but it's delivered this way:

```
Percentage

3456
4444
325
```

Expected values:

```
Percentage

34,56
44,44
32,5
```

When I use gsub o sub I can't conserve my column as numeric. It doesn't matter if I use "." or "," the result is character.

Thanks!

Comment: `paste(substr(Percentage, 1, 2), substr(Pecrentage, 3, 5), sep = ",")` ?

Comment: *"can't conserve my column as numeric"* --- anytime you try to add string to numbers, the whole will become a string. What are you trying to do, convert these to a `,`-based-locale decimal number?

Comment: @AllanCameron That works but the column becomes <chr>

Comment: @r2evans I''m trying to make a number of one or two digits, the others are decimals.

Comment: Clara, I think you missed my point. First: the use of `gsub` or `paste` or similar *string* function will always convert a number to a string, period. Second, are you using a locale where the comma separates whole numbers (to the left) from fractional (to the right)? If your locale is comma-based, then why is your number being read in incorrectly in the first place? If your R is already set up to be comma-based, can you use `x / ifelse(x < 1000, 10, 100)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make use of `comma` from `formattable` which will modify the `format` while keeping the `numeric` as it is

```
df1$Percentage <- formattable::comma(df1$Percentage, big.interval = 2, digits = 0)
```

-checking

```
> df1
  Percentage
1      34,56
2      44,44
3       3,25
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Percentage: 'formattable' int  34,56 44,44 3,25
  ..- attr(*, "formattable")=List of 4
  .. ..$ formatter: chr "formatC"
  .. ..$ format   :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ format      : chr "f"
  .. .. ..$ big.mark    : chr ","
  .. .. ..$ digits      : num 0
  .. .. ..$ big.interval: num 2
  .. ..$ preproc  : NULL
  .. ..$ postproc : NULL
```

It is also possible to do calculations as it is a numeric column

```
> df1$Percentage * 100
[1] 34,56,00 44,44,00 3,25,00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Percentage = c(3456L, 4444L, 325L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked, but the type of value is "<formttbl>" and when I save it as excel and I open it, the numbers appear without comma

Comment: @Clara you can't have `numeric` type per se and have `,`.  formattable changes the character by modifying the format.  Not clear about the excel part though.  That could be an issue in the excel formatting

Comment: And if I use "."? I want to specify where the decimal digits start. Thanks!

Comment: @Clara Then, you can just `format` and convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` i.e. `as.numeric(format(df1$Percentage, big.mark =".", big.interval = 2))#[1] 34.56 44.44  3.25`

Comment: Thank u so much! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

We can make it in another way:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

x <- c("3333", "4223", "34215")

P1 <- x %>%
        str_replace_all("(^\\d{2})", "\\1.") %>%
        as.double() %>%
        data.frame() 

colnames()[1] <- "Percentage"
```

---

**Result:**

```
> P1
  Percentage
1     33.330
2     42.230
3     34.215
```